# any PDF plugin for cakePHP?

Tags: pdf, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to implement in a page/view of a form an option to generate a PDF file; looking for information I have seen that cakepdf exists, but there is hardly any information on how to implement/install it and it seems to be outdated.
Are there other options compatible with CakePHP?

Comment: [**CakePdf**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) is actively being maintained (though there's not much to do), and it works fine for what it's supposed to do. The docs contain everything needed for the basic setup, so I'd suggest that you try it, and check back if you have any specific problems with it.

Comment: okey I will try thank you

Answer (score -1):

Best option to use is https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ via https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf ... we use this to generate PDF documents in our CakePHP solution.

Comment: thank you. i will try. I think it's a good idea